# quadratic equations solving function on python

Tags: python

```
    def quadSolve(a,b,c,r):
        r = list()
        if a != 0:
            if b**2 - 4*a*c > 0:
                k1 = (-b + (b**2-4*a*c)**(1/2))/2*a
                k2 = (-b - (b**2-4*a*c)**(1/2))/2*a
                r.append(k1)
                r.append(k2)
            if b**2 - 4*a*c == 0:
                k0 = -b / 2*a
                r.append(k0)
            if b**2 - 4*a*c < 0:
                r.clear()
        if a == 0 and b != 0:
            k3 = -c/b
            r.append(k3)
        if a==0  and b == 0:
            r.clear()
        return r

    main():
        print("ax^2 + bx + c = 0")
        a = input("a is?: ")
        b = input("b is?: ")
        c = input("c is?: ")
        r = list()
        answer = quadSolve(a,b,c,r)
        if len(answer) == 0:
            print("no roots")        
        else:
            print("answer is", answer)
        print()
```

Can someone point out what's wrong here??
I'm trying to make a function that solves quadratic equations using list r
I don't know what is wrong with the main code.

Comment: Could you include what your expected result is, from a specific input, and what error you are receiving? The first error you should receive is an `unsupported operand type`, because the `a`, `b`, and `c` variables aren't integers.

Answer (score 0):

Look, IDK how to use the "def something ():", but this is the way that it ran for me:

> My code is:

```py
## The rules:

# function ==  ax2 + bx + c
# delta == b2 - 4ac
# if delta == 0: one answer
# if delta < 0: don't exist answer E R
# if delta > 0: two answers

# result is: (+/- r/delta - b)/2a

answer = 'answer ='

print('ax^2 + bx^2 + c = 0')
a = int(input('a is: '))
b = int(input('b is: '))
c = int(input('c is: '))

delta = b**2 - 4*a*c

if delta > 0:
    x = (delta**(1/2) - b)/(2*a)
    x2 = (-delta**(1/2) - b)/(2*a)
    print(answer, x, x2)
if delta == 0:
    x = (-b)/(2*a)
    print(answer, x)
if delta < 0:
    print("Doesn't exist Real solution.")
```

> PyShell example:

```py
ax^2 + bx^2 + c = 0
a is: 1
b is: -4
c is: -12
answer = 6.0 -2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do, based in your code is:

> Look the `int(input())`was added  and the `main():` was deleted

```py
def quadSolve(a,b,c,r):
    r = list()
    if a != 0:
        if b**2 - 4*a*c > 0:
            k1 = (-b + (b**2-4*a*c)**(1/2))/2*a
            k2 = (-b - (b**2-4*a*c)**(1/2))/2*a
            r.append(k1)
            r.append(k2)
        if b**2 - 4*a*c == 0:
            k0 = -b / 2*a
            r.append(k0)
        if b**2 - 4*a*c < 0:
            r.clear()
    if a == 0 and b != 0:
        k3 = -c/b
        r.append(k3)
    if a==0  and b == 0:
        r.clear()
    return r

print("ax^2 + bx + c = 0")
a = int(input("a is?: "))
b = int(input("b is?: "))
c = int(input("c is?: "))
r = list()
answer = quadSolve(a,b,c,r)
if len(answer) == 0:
    print("no roots")        
else:
    print("answer is", answer)
print()
```